# Upper bar of webpage messes up when resizing window or opening webpage in phone

Tags: html, css

I want an upper bar like StackOverflow. Whenever I resize my page, it should automatically adjust. But in my website, whenever I resize my window or open it in my phone the content on the right corner moves to the next line and messes the whole navigation bar. I have tried many ways but nothing worked.

```css
#search {
  position: relative;
  left: 15%;
}

#sign-in {
  position: relative;
  left: 32%;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
  font-size: 20px;
}

#about {
  position: relative;
  left: 39%;
  font-size: 20px;
  font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
}

#search-icon {
  position: relative;
  font-size: 30px;
  top: 5px;
}

input {
  height: 25px;
  width: 400px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

input::-webkit-input-placeholder {
  font-size: 15px;
  position: relative;
  left: 12px;
  font-style: italic;
  bottom: 1px;
}

#logo {
  font-family: Georgia, 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
  color: brown;
  position: relative;
  left: 3%;
}

#search-box {
  position: relative;
  bottom: 5px;
}

#arrow {
  position: relative;
  left: 39%;
  top: 7px;
}

#upperBar {
  background-color: rgb(233, 233, 233);
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  left: 0px;
  position: fixed;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

```html
<div id="upperBar">
  <h1>
    <span id="logo">HSmedic</span>
    <span id="search">
      <input id="search-box" placeholder="search questions, books or profiles">
    </span>
    <span id="sign-in">Sign In</span>
    <span id="about">About</span>
  </h1>
</div>
```

Comment: Have you tried looking into Bootstrap for dynamic adjustment of content based on screen size?

Comment: This upper bar you refer to is called Nav bar/Menu bar[Navigation Bar]. Try and use bootstrap for automatic resize based on resolution of window.

Comment: What is bootstrap?

Comment: Bootstrap is the most popular HTML, CSS, and JavaScript framework for developing responsive, mobile-first web sites.

Comment: Thanks, I will try.